# Async / Await Task returns no value

Tags: c#, async-await

What the code does is loops a datagrid of URLs checks in the html for a certain string and returns data accordingly, very basic so far.

I'm trying to understand the await / async methods better, i have a fairly ok grasp so far but i have hit a snag, the code i have so far:

**FormMain.cs**

```
        public async Task RunAsyncAnalyzer()
        {
            try
            {
                BtnPerformLinkAnalysis.Enabled = false;
                if (DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridViewLinks.Rows)
                    {
                        row.Cells[2].Value = await Task.Run(() => { Helpers.GetLinkPlatformType(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); });
                    }
                }
                BtnPerformLinkAnalysis.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
            }

        }

        private async void BtnPerformLinkAnalysis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await RunAsyncAnalyzer();
        }
```

**Helpers.cs**

```
        public static string GetLinkPlatformType(string url) {
            string platform_type = "......";
            try { 
                var html = GetWebPageHTML(url);

                if (html.Contains("Start the discussion…")) {
                    platform_type = "DISCUZ|CAN_COMMENT";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
            }
            return platform_type;
        }
```

The error i am getting is: `cannot convert type 'void' to 'object'` and it is on this line: `row.Cells[2].Value = await Task.Run(() => { Helpers.GetLinkPlatformType(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); });`

It also says above it: `Awaited Task returns no value` but the method `GetLinkPlatformType` does return a value it is not a `void` i cannot see what the issue is i know i am over looking something but i'm not entirely sure what, any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: your GetLinkPlatformType is also not async so there really is no need to use Task.Run(..) to execute it. Which also means all of this code is sync so no need for async/await anywhere in this example code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that your task is not returning anything, you missed the `return`.

```
row.Cells[2].Value = await Task.Run(() => { return Helpers.GetLinkPlatformType(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); });
```

Otherwise it's just a task that does something but does not return anything.

Also, as @leszek mentioned in the comments, here's another approach:

```
row.Cells[2].Value = await Task.Run(() => Helpers.GetLinkPlatformType(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) );
```

Hope it helps!